# this.isSpecified is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code inside a file

```
function Period(id, firstMonth, firstDay, lastMonth, lastDay) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstMonth = firstMonth;
    this.firstDay = firstDay;
    this.lastMonth= lastMonth;
    this.lastDay= lastDay;
}
```

---

```
Period.prototype.isSpecified = function () {
   return !! this.firstMonth && !! this.lastMonth;
};
```

---

```
   Period.prototype.containsDate = function (date) {
        getSeasonDates(Period, date);
    };
```

---

```
Period.prototype.getPeriodMonths = function (date) {

    getPeriodDates(date);

    ...

}
```

---

```
function getPeriodDates(Period, date){

    if (!date || !date.isValid()) {
        throw new Error('invalid date passed to period.containsDate(): ' + date);
    }

    if (!this.isSpecified()) {
        return false;
    }
```

When I run this code it throws an error saying `TypeError: this.isSpecified is not a function`.

Does anyone knows what is wrong with it?

I'm trying to call the function `getPeriodDates()` inside `Period.prototype.getPeriodMonths`.

Comment: `this` is not _this_.

Comment: When you call `getPeriodDates` as `getPeriodDates()`, `this` is `Window`. Thus the error.

Comment: Why would `this` be a new instance of `Period` inside the `getPeriodDates` method ?

Comment: can I call it different inside that method?

Comment: `getPeriodDates.call(this, date);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you missed scope when calling `this.isSpecified()`
Let's try  `getPeriodDates.call(this, date);`

You can get more detail here: http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/